# Find clickable world maps

Tags: jquery, html, css, flash, animation

Can I get something like this http://myffi.biz/ , which selects the continents when I hover on the languages?  I have searched a lot for this kind of map but have not been able to find any.

Comment: You might be able to start with something from ActiveDen: http://activeden.net/searches?term=world+map&type=files But this is not really programming related -- voting to close.

Comment: The example you give is IMHO poor design.  The map is not clickable.   So the visitor to the site needs to understand sufficient English to navigate the menu.  Also highlighting just the continents and not the countries is a gimmick but not gimmicky enough (a proper job would highlight the individual countries at the next menu level).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in (at least) Flash or Jquery & CSS.... but you'd need to either build it from scratch, or find ready plugins/code and adapt it for your needs. The outlines for the continents would be a vector image that you can buy on any a stock images site (like istockphoto.com) and then export into optimised images for web display.

My strong recommendation is that you think of something simpler for your interface, as going through all that tweakery isn't worth it unless it's a central and necessary part of your site.

Comment: I agree with you from the interface POV, but my client wants something of that sort, and she is very rigid on that! Spent one whole day on this and couldn't find anything close to it.

They just need it on the front page so as to show that its multilingual.

Comment: Wikipedia is also a goldmine for free vector maps, for example http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File_talk:BlankMap-World6.svg/Documentation

Answer (score 0):

http://www.synergetechsolutions.com/blog/analytics-world-map-control

This already has the world broken down into highlightable regions. You can easily add your own regions with invisible hitboxes over text areas if you want a separate "menu" region which highlights on hover.